# Is the PHP CURL api cleaner/faster/better than using streams for HTTP/HTTPS access?

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I currently use pretty exclusively the PHP stream context functionality (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to access HTTP resources and I've been able to successfully use it to do PUTs, DELETEs, POSTs, manage cookies and do just about everything I've needed to do. I originally started using it because I had SSL issues with earlier Debian PHP cURL builds (there was an OpenSSL double-initialization issue within the Apache process that errored out when trying to access SSL urls): those are probably fixed now but I've not had occasion to go back.

In discussions with a friend he contended that the cURL api is faster/better so I wanted to ask: is there any definite experience/knowledge about which option is superior, and in what ways?

Comment: cURL is [usually speedier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance) with request processing. But I wouldn't classify the API as "better". Why are you using the raw fopen/stream functions instead of a HTTP utility class?

Comment: Laziness, mostly: I wrote a chunk of code 2 years ago and have been copy-pasting it everywhere I need it, and its quite frankly so few lines of code usually that I didn't bother wrapping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to performance, [cURL wins <strike>by a lot</strike> consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance). I won't deny that it's harder to use and it might not matter for general use, but the difference was pretty dramatic and I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: Please also see the second answer for results that relativize "a lot".

Comment: Yeah, I did see that; the fact that the tests were run a year apart doesn't help the earlier one's case. Nonetheless, the end head-to-head result is the same. I did update my answer to reflect that though.

Comment: This was 6 years ago.  Does it still hold true now that PHP has gone through one major and several minor revisions?

Answer (score 7):

Streams are pretty neat in my experience. You probably know it already, but here's a post on streams with a twist in case not:

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/44/php-iterators-and-streams-are-awesome

Curl is nice and fast, and simple; but I honestly wouldn't prefer one or the other for performance reasons. I've never measured but I doubt it makes that much of a difference in comparison with the overhead of doing a remote request in the first place.

Comment: Didn't know about the iterator bits, and the S3 stream wrapper is quite nifty: will have to dig into that. Thanks for the answer.