# What is faster than curl?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to build out a script that creates domain API registration URLs and sends them through the appropriate API to complete the registration. Right now I'm using curl and each request takes roughly 2 seconds. Are there faster languages or methods to doing this vs. using PHP to do the processing.

Comment: If you're hitting an API, cURL is probably not the bottleneck. The speed the server responds is likely to be at least part of the cause.

Comment: That's what I am thinking with a VPS being at 10Mb up/down.

Would doing this through using C++ be better by overall cutting out my servers VPS connection?

Comment: I'm not following why you think a change in how you make the request (processing time) is going to affect the roundtrip time

Comment: What tacos_tacos_tacos says. Also, curl is already written in C. It's unlikely to get much faster than that

Comment: Network latency and the speed of the other server's response is *by far and away* be the slowest part of this process. You cannot fix that with code.

Answer (score 3):

I was once in a position where cURL was not an option by the constraints of the project I was working on.  I learned about streams and ended up using code similar to what is in this article. http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

That is only another method, I've never compared efficiency. There is another thread on SO asking a similar question. I would assume that each has its advantages in various circumstances.

[Is the PHP CURL api cleaner/faster/better than using streams for HTTP/HTTPS access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025668/is-the-php-curl-api-cleaner-faster-better-than-using-streams-for-http-https-acce?rq=1)