# Is there a faster/better way to check if an URL is reachable than cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm building a PHP-script that checks if an URL is reachable. This is currently achieved with cURL. This is script is part of a bigger application that calls this cURL-Script very often .

So I am wondering if there is a faster/better way than cURL. So far i couldnt find anything except this [article](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/) from this question: [What is faster than curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149042/what-is-faster-than-curl)

This doesn't help me since I have the following requirements for the check:

- Must follow redirects
- Must return a HTTP-status-code (like 200 or
  404)
- Must be able to authenticate (htaccess)

EDIT:

- Must work in PHP safemode

Comment: You can try using file_get_contents with a header context and run a test. http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: The problem isn't in `cURL` being slow, the problem lies in the whole request > follow response > finally arrive back. If you swap out `cURL` for any other mechanism/library that understands HTTP, that won't make DNS, remote web servers and scripts work any faster.

Comment: @Mjh Could you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, the cause of slowness isn't the `cURL` library. There's a whole system behind HTTP, such as DNS, web server(s), the connectivity to those servers and ultimately - every site / service uses some sort of server-side language to perform work, which can be slow as well. You need to find out what exactly in this chain isn't responding fast enough - is it DNS? Is it the connection of your server to the service you're connecting to? Is the service itself slow?

You can be 100% sure that it's not `cURL`.